# Protractor parallel execution - selenium bind exception

Tags: selenium, protractor

We've been trying to run our protractor e2e UI tests in parallel (maxInstance = 3).
However, we have started seeing the following error (it doesn't happen straight away, but appears at some point during the execution) and are having hard time understanding where it comes from:

*> [06:01:18] E/BlockingProxy - Got status 13 from selenium { stacktrace:

> 'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already
> in use: connect\r\n\tat
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$3(WebDriverServlet.java:252)\r\n\tat
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\r\nCaused by:
> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect\r\n\tat
> java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)\r\n\tat
> java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat
> java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat
> sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat
> sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat
> sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat
> sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat
> sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat
> sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown
> Source)\r\n\tat
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.Passthrough.handle(Passthrough.java:104)\r\n\tat
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.RemoteSession.execute(RemoteSession.java:127)\r\n\tat
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$3(WebDriverServlet.java:247)\r\n\t...
> 5 more\r\n', 15:57:32      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]   stackTrace:
> 15:57:32      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]    [ { fileName:
> 'WebDriverServlet.java', 15:57:32      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]
> methodName: 'lambda$handle$3', 15:57:32      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY
>
> ## 01-6]        className: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet', 15:57:32
>
> [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]        lineNumber: 252 }, 15:57:32
> [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]      { fileName: null, 15:57:32
> [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]        methodName: 'call', 15:57:32
> [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]        className:
> 'java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter', 15:57:32      [exec]
> [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]        lineNumber: -1 }, 15:57:32      [exec]
> [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]      { fileName: null, 15:57:32      [exec]
> [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]        methodName: 'run', 15:57:32      [exec]
> [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]        className:
> 'java.util.concurrent.FutureTask', 15:57:32      [exec] [chrome ANY
> ANY #01-6]        lineNumber: -1 }, 15:57:32      [exec] [chrome ANY
> ANY #01-6]      { fileName: null, 15:57:32      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY
>
> ## 01-6]        methodName: 'runWorker', 15:57:32      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]        className:
>
> 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor', 15:57:32      [exec]
> [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]        lineNumber: -1 }, 15:57:32      [exec]
> [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]      { fileName: null, 15:57:32      [exec]
> [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]        methodName: 'run', 15:57:32      [exec]
> [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]        className:
> 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker', 15:57:32      [exec]
> [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]        lineNumber: -1 }, 15:57:32      [exec]
> [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]      { fileName: null, 15:57:32      [exec]
> [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]        methodName: 'run', 15:57:32      [exec]
> [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]        className: 'java.lang.Thread', 15:57:32
> [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]        lineNumber: -1 } ], 15:57:32
> [exec] [chrome ANY ANY #01-6]   message: 'java.net.BindException:
> Address already in use: connect', 15:57:32      [exec] [chrome ANY ANY
>
> ## 01-6]   error: 'unknown error' }*

Has anyone seen this error and what could be the cause?

Cheers,
Lucy

Comment: are all instances using the same chromedriver port?  that's likely the problem

Comment: @CoreyGoldbeeg, not really sure what you mean. Selenium is started at port 4444, and I suppose the browser instances are bound to different client ports, but I don't really know how to check that and whether there is a setting for that for protractor.

Comment: After some digging around, I see that the chrome instances are started on different ports. Log:16:34:05      [exec] Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 44350
16:34:05      [exec] Only local connections are allowed.
16:34:05      [exec] Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 19547
16:34:05      [exec] Only local connections are allowed.
16:34:05      [exec] Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 10982

Comment: your client code communicates with selenium server on port 4444... then selenium communicates with Chromedriver on Port 9515.  Chromedriver blocks while running... so your your test execution is essentially serialized.  You can use ChromeDriverService for managing chromedriver.

Comment: Yeah, but this shouldn't be the expected behavior. Here is what I found -  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2152#c9. Any ideas if this can be work-arounded, like for example can chromedriver be forced to handle requests sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** What fixed the issue in the end was adding a TcpTimedWaitDelay in Windows registry and setting it to 30 seconds.